# Ransack регистронезависимый поиск на кириллице. Как?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Использую `имя_поля_cont`. на латинице с поиском все как и должно быть с этим предикатом, ищет независимо от регистра. Однако, с кириллицей беда... понятно, что перекодирование кириллицы делается по другому, но как сделать это в Ransack - не могу понять. Спасибо.
**Поправка.** На локале все работает, ситуация только на продакшене.

Comment: СУБД какая используется и какие операционные системы локально и на продакшене?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился, проблема была совсем не в Ransack, кодировка в Postgres на продакшене была SQL-ASCII, тогда как на девелопменте была UTF-8. После смены кодировки на продакшене все заработало как нужно.